# Microtype and Minion Pro

Tags: microtype, minionpro

Before I formatted my computer (Windows 7 Pro 64 bit) I had MiKTeX (32 bit installed) and with respect to Minion Pro everything was smooth. I have been using ShareLaTeX since then and today I installed MiKTeX and Minion Pro, and somehow something is broken.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[
  fullfamily,
  opticals,
  textosf,
  mathlf,
  loosequotes
]{MinionPro}

\usepackage[
  toc,
  eqno,
  enum,
  bib,
  lineno
]{tabfigures} %employs tabular figures

\usepackage[
%  protrusion  =true,
%  expansion   =true,
%  tracking    =true,
%  letterspace =50,
%  final
]{microtype}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

The above setup works without a problem (`pdflatex`). However, as soon as I uncomment any of the `microtype options I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package microtype.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.26 

The package microtype has already been loaded with options:
  [kerning=true]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [ protrusion =true, ]
Adding the global options:
  kerning=true, protrusion =true, 
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
```

(Adding the option described in the error message does not help.)

If comment `Minion Pro` options:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[
%  fullfamily,
%  opticals,
%  textosf,
%  mathlf,
%  loosequotes
]{MinionPro}

\usepackage[
  toc,
  eqno,
  enum,
  bib,
  lineno
]{tabfigures} %employs tabular figures

\usepackage[
  protrusion  =true,
  expansion   =true,
  tracking    =true,
  letterspace =50,
  final
]{microtype}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I get:

```
Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\j '
(microtype)                in font encoding `T1' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `microtype.cfg/228(protrusion)'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/sl' in size <10> not availab
le
(Font)              Font shape `T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/it' tried instead on input l
```

So (hopefully without being labeled as "too local") what might it be that is broken?

Comment: The package `MinionPro` loads `microtype` already as you can read from the documentation. So you might get some option clash. Maybe using `\PassOptionsToPackage{<options>}{microtype}` is an option before loading `MinionPro`

Comment: @faltfe If that is the case, why did I not have that problem before?

Comment: I don't know this was just a wild guess and a starting point.

Comment: @faltfe Your suggestion magically solves *everything.* You should perhaps make it an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just converting my comment to an answer as suggested by @blackened

The package `MinionPro` loads microtype already as you can read from the documentation. So you might get some option clash. Maybe using `\PassOptionsToPackage{<options>}{microtype}` is an option before loading `MinionPro`